# How to check the value that is already present in Observable Collection

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, observablecollection

Hi guys I want to ask one thing ,I have one datagrid and I am adding multiple rows in it but I want to check that the duplicate values should not be entered in a datagrid.

My code is :

```
public ObservableCollection<VLANSPropertyClass> vlan { get; set; }

void AddVlans()
        {
            if ((String.IsNullOrEmpty(VlanName)) ||
                 String.IsNullOrEmpty(VlanID)    ||
                 String.IsNullOrEmpty(VlanIP1)   ||
                 String.IsNullOrEmpty(VlanIP2)   ||
                 String.IsNullOrEmpty(VlanIP3)   ||
                 String.IsNullOrEmpty(VlanIP4)   ||
                 String.IsNullOrEmpty(SelectedVlanPort))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please fill the empty fields", "Alert", MessageBoxButton.OK);
            }
            else
            {
                var serial = new VLANSPropertyClass();

                serial.S_No = vlan.Count + 1;

                serial.vname = VlanName;

                serial.vid = VlanID;

                serial.ip = VlanIP1 + "." + VlanIP2 + "." + VlanIP3 + "." + VlanIP4;

                serial.mask = Vlanmask1 + "." + Vlanmask2 + "." + Vlanmask3 + "." + Vlanmask4;

                serial.vports = SelectedVlanPort;


                vlan.Add(serial);
            }
        }
```

I want to show a message box that a user is entering a duplicate values. Any help would be greatly appreciable. Please I want a solution in a hurry.

Comment: What is the condition that makes it duplicate? If all fields match or..?

Comment: If VlanName ,VlanID,VlanIP1,VlanIP2,VlanIP3,VlanIP4,SelectedVlanPort

Comment: If VlanName ,VlanID,VlanIP1,VlanIP2,VlanIP3,VlanIP4,SelectedVlanPort already exist then it should display a message box

Answer (score 0):

here is a quick one

```
bool itemExists = vlan.Any(item=>
{
    return (item.vname == VlanName) && 
           (item.ip == VlanIP1 + "." + VlanIP2 + "." + VlanIP3 + "." + VlanIP4) && 
           (item.vname == VlanName) && 
           (item.vports == SelectedVlanPort);
}

if(itemExists)
{
     //show message
} 
else
{
     //add new item 
}
```

in short you are using a linq method `Any` to see if there is an item matching with the specified condition. it will return if there is match otherwise false

you may need to import namespace `using System.Linq;` if `Any` method is not available

Comment: Why not use `Object.Equals` with a custom implementation?

Comment: @Herdo indeed correct, that is one of the answer and I thought the same too. but I was not sure if OP have access to `VLANSPropertyClass`'s implementation. and I thought the proposed may work in all possible scenarios.

Comment: Can you please do some more I didn't understand ,I need a solution according to the code I have given above please..thanks

Comment: bool itemexists()
        {

            var item = new VLANSPropertyClass();
            return
                   (item.vname == VlanName) &&
                   (item.ip == VlanIP1 + "." + VlanIP2 + "." + VlanIP3 + "." + VlanIP4) &&
                   (item.vname == VlanName) &&
                   (item.vports == SelectedVlanPort);
}